# Unity: Navigation bar overlaying content

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, navigation

I'm having an issue where the Android navigation bar is convering my content on only some specific phones.

I'm setting

```
        ApplicationChrome.statusBarState = ApplicationChrome.navigationBarState = ApplicationChrome.States.Visible;
```

on the opening scene but the content still remains underneath the navigation bar on Pixel 3 XL (Android 10). It appears correctly on a Galaxy S8 however so I'm at a loss :/.

For what it's worth I've tried all possible ApplicationChrome.States and I am not seeing a solution. I've also tried it both ways with the application being full screen and not full screen with no luck.

I'm using Unity 2019.1.14f1.

Thank you!